# MMQGIS plugin causes QGIS crash while geocoding

Tags: qgis, geocoding, mmqgis

When trying to geocode data with MMQGIS plugin (Google Maps), QGIS crashes (not responding). I even tried to divide data into smaller sets but it does not help.

Comment: Which version of qgis do you use, which os?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.  It would freeze at a slightly different point each time, but usually around 50-100k searched streets into the search, according to the counter at bottom left.

Finally, after searching in vain for anyone else who'd had the problem (besides you), and restarting the program quite a few times, I saw that QGIS was still using quite a bit of resources, and decided to let it run.

Lo and behold, it took a few hours, but it's unfrozen and reports being finished.

Unfortunately it still didn't find my few test locations.
So not sure whether it'll prove to be great help to you or not!
But hopefully knowing it may still be running (and it still has to scan one by one through the streets list [20 million streets in the US file I'm using] regardless of how many sites you search) will turn out to help.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on your file size. QGIS freezes after it has geocoded the first 8 records for me when I do more than 10 addresses. My recent file had N=1,166 records and it took at least 10 minutes. Google apparently limits the rate of geocodes per second. Bottom line: The larger the file, the longer the wait time. QGIS will return to normal after all your records have been geocoded.

Answer (score 1):

Try out the RUGeocoder plugin as an alternative

Answer (score 1):

I've been experiencing issues with continued crashes of mmqgis geocoder on medium sized address lists (N=1,500 and greater).

Here's the following quick fix:

1. Install Google Earth Pro for free
   http://www.google.com/earth/download/gep/agree.html just use the free
   license code at sign in.
2. Follow these instructions. https://youtu.be/7Lwyejdq08k Keep in mind that this version of Google Earth Pro limits batch geocoding to N=2,500 addresses at a time. Split file into batches if needed.
3. Export the created address file via right click Save As to KML
4. Import the KML file via Add Vector Layer in QGIS and save as SHP
   if you need to http://www.igismap.com/convert-kml-shapefile-qgis/

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and in my case, it had something to do with the encoding of my csv file.

Make sure your csv file is encoded in "utf-8", not "ANSI".  A simple way to save as a "utf-8" is to create your csv file in excel.  Open the file with Notepad and then resave as a csv and within Notepad, at the bottom of the save screen is a way to designate which encoding you want.